# "goto was unexpected at this time" - batch file

Tags: batch-file

I don't know why but for some reason that always comes up or something similar

```
@echo off
echo would you like to go to the next part (y/n)
set /p 1= type y or n here:

if %1% == Y goto 1

if not %1% == Y exit

:1
echo hi
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an urgent need to use numbers as a variable, I recommend you to use only those shown in the following solution:

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
echo would you like to go to the next part (y/n)
set /p "1=type y or n here: "
if /i "!1!"=="Y" goto 1

if /i not "!1!"=="Y" exit

:1
echo hi
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't use numbers as **VARIABLES**.

`%1` means 'the first parameter to the procedure, hence your line becomes

```
if % == Y goto 1
```

change the variable `1` to `one` and try again